# Razor View Engine,issue with ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am new to Razor view engine and i was trying for something like this

```
<span class="@(Model.ID == null ? "promptTabActive" : "myclass")"></span>
```

But once it is rendered it is showing as

```
 <span class=""></span>
```

I changed it to

```
<span class="@(Model.ID == null ? "promptTabActive11" : "myclass")"></span>
```

and it is started appearing like

```
<span class="promptTabActive11"></span>
```

weared.. i got frustated out of it.. What is wrong with the word "promptTabActive" in razor view engine?? is it a key word.. anything else from the word "promptTabActive" is coming properly but only this.

Help required..

Comment: You need to post some more code, formatted properly. Also, the part where you said "But once it is rendered it is showing as..." you don't have anything there for us to look at.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; I get `<span>class="promptTabActive"</span>`, as required. Are you sure you don't have something like R# "correcting" your html as you paste it?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - to be fair, the OP is asking why promptTabActive isn't displayed in the first example.

Comment: are you saying that you want the text to appear inside the span tag? `<span>class="promptTabActive"</span>`

Comment: @LukeDuddridge - No, I think they are asking why the first example does not include the text promptTabActive in the class attribute, and why just adding 11 to the end of the class name 'fixes' it.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are show can not possibly produce the result that you are showing. You have the `class` attribute outside the `span` tag in the code, but somehow it ended up inside the `span` tag in the result?

The code should look like this:

```
<span class="@(Model.ID == null ? "promptTabActive" : "myclass")"></span>
```